# implementing a android webkit plugin, where to find the official doc?

Tags: android, plugins, browser, webkit

i am trying to implement a webkit plugin. I know the webkit plugin adopts the NPAPI, so I am looking up from mozilla website, finding it helpful (for moziila, it's Gecko plugin, but also adopts NPAPI).
Well, there still some problem,
for example, when i write the NPP_Destroy method, i need invoke the NPNetscapeFuncs's releaseobject. I checked the NPNetscapeFuncs definition from android source code, the releaseobject is defined like this:

```
typedef struct _NPNetscapeFuncs {
uint16_t size;
uint16_t version;

NPN_GetURLProcPtr geturl;
NPN_PostURLProcPtr posturl;
NPN_RequestReadProcPtr requestread;
NPN_NewStreamProcPtr newstream;
NPN_WriteProcPtr write;
NPN_DestroyStreamProcPtr destroystream;
NPN_StatusProcPtr status;
NPN_UserAgentProcPtr uagent;
NPN_MemAllocProcPtr memalloc;
NPN_MemFreeProcPtr memfree;
NPN_MemFlushProcPtr memflush;
NPN_ReloadPluginsProcPtr reloadplugins;
NPN_GetJavaEnvProcPtr getJavaEnv;
NPN_GetJavaPeerProcPtr getJavaPeer;
NPN_GetURLNotifyProcPtr geturlnotify;
NPN_PostURLNotifyProcPtr posturlnotify;
NPN_GetValueProcPtr getvalue;
NPN_SetValueProcPtr setvalue;
NPN_InvalidateRectProcPtr invalidaterect;
NPN_InvalidateRegionProcPtr invalidateregion;
NPN_ForceRedrawProcPtr forceredraw;

NPN_GetStringIdentifierProcPtr getstringidentifier;
NPN_GetStringIdentifiersProcPtr getstringidentifiers;
NPN_GetIntIdentifierProcPtr getintidentifier;
NPN_IdentifierIsStringProcPtr identifierisstring;
NPN_UTF8FromIdentifierProcPtr utf8fromidentifier;
NPN_IntFromIdentifierProcPtr intfromidentifier;
NPN_CreateObjectProcPtr createobject;
NPN_RetainObjectProcPtr retainobject;
NPN_ReleaseObjectProcPtr releaseobject;
NPN_InvokeProcPtr invoke;
NPN_InvokeDefaultProcPtr invokeDefault;
NPN_EvaluateProcPtr evaluate;
NPN_GetPropertyProcPtr getproperty;
NPN_SetPropertyProcPtr setproperty;
NPN_RemovePropertyProcPtr removeproperty;
NPN_HasPropertyProcPtr hasproperty;
NPN_HasMethodProcPtr hasmethod;
NPN_ReleaseVariantValueProcPtr releasevariantvalue;
NPN_SetExceptionProcPtr setexception;
NPN_PushPopupsEnabledStateProcPtr pushpopupsenabledstate;
NPN_PopPopupsEnabledStateProcPtr poppopupsenabledstate;
NPN_EnumerateProcPtr enumerate;
NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCallProcPtr pluginthreadasynccall;
NPN_ConstructProcPtr construct;
NPN_GetValueForURLProcPtr getvalueforurl;
NPN_SetValueForURLProcPtr setvalueforurl;
NPN_GetAuthenticationInfoProcPtr getauthenticationinfo;
NPN_ScheduleTimerProcPtr scheduletimer;
NPN_UnscheduleTimerProcPtr unscheduletimer;
NPN_PopUpContextMenuProcPtr popupcontextmenu;
NPN_ConvertPointProcPtr convertpoint;
```

} NPNetscapeFuncs;

But the NPN_ReleaseObjectProcPtr(in fact most of the functions)apparantly is not declared in mozilla . So i cannot get any help about it.

Do i have referred the wrong place in mozilla for help? Anyone know about this?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't implemented one before but have used documentation from http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.documentfoundation.libreoffice.devel/18620 for other things. Hope this helps

Comment: thanks! it is more helpful than the others, though the webpage looks a little un-formatted:)